# xamarin forms Jsonreaderexception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list showing stores on a page, upon clicking each store, corresponding categories and products are shown on a lists in  another page. Stores, categories and products are displayed using Api calls.I am getting everything correct, but while navigating back and forth many times between store page and product page,Getting this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered 
while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Using breakpoint, not able to see the source of exception. How to handle this exception?

Edit: I am getting this html just before exception

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Too Many Requests</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
        html {
            line-height: 1.15;
                -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        header,
        nav,
        section {
            display: block;
        }

        figcaption,
        main {
            display: block;
        }

        a {
            background-color: transparent;
            -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
        }

        strong {
            font-weight: inherit;
        }

        strong {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        code {
            font-family: monospace, monospace;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        dfn {
            font-style: italic;
        }

        svg:not(:root) {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        button,
        input {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
            line-height: 1.15;
            margin: 0;
        }

        button,
        input {
            overflow: visible;
        }

        button {
            text-transform: none;
        }

        button,
        html [type="button"],
        [type="reset"],
        [type="submit"] {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
        }

        button::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
            border-style: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        button:-moz-focusring,
        [type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
        [type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
        [type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
            outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
        }

        legend {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
            color: inherit;
            display: table;
            max-width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            white-space: normal;
        }

        [type="checkbox"],
        [type="radio"] {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
        }

        [type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        [type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
            height: auto;
        }

        [type="search"] {
            -webkit-appearance: textfield;
            outline-offset: -2px;
        }

        [type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
        [type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }

        ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
            font: inherit;
        }

        menu {
            display: block;
        }

        canvas {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        template {
            display: none;
        }

        [hidden] {
            display: none;
        }

        html {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
                    box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
        }

        button {
            background: transparent;
            padding: 0;
        }

        button:focus {
            outline: 1px dotted;
            outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
        }

        *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            border-width: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #dae1e7;
        }

        button,
        [type="button"],
        [type="reset"],
        [type="submit"] {
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        button,
        input {
            font-family: inherit;
        }

        input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: inherit;
            opacity: .5;
        }

        input:-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: inherit;
            opacity: .5;
        }

        input::-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: inherit;
            opacity: .5;
        }

        input::placeholder {
            color: inherit;
            opacity: .5;
        }

        button,
        [role=button] {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .bg-transparent {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .bg-white {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .bg-teal-light {
            background-color: #64d5ca;
        }

        .bg-blue-dark {
            background-color: #2779bd;
        }

        .bg-indigo-light {
            background-color: #7886d7;
        }

        .bg-purple-light {
            background-color: #a779e9;
        }

        .bg-no-repeat {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .bg-cover {
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .border-grey-light {
            border-color: #dae1e7;
        }

        .hover\:border-grey:hover {
            border-color: #b8c2cc;
        }

        .rounded-lg {
            border-radius: .5rem;
        }

        .border-2 {
            border-width: 2px;
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .flex {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
        }

        .items-center {
            -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                    align-items: center;
        }

        .justify-center {
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                    justify-content: center;
        }

        .font-sans {
            font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
        }

        .font-light {
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .font-bold {
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .font-black {
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .h-1 {
            height: .25rem;
        }

        .leading-normal {
            line-height: 1.5;
        }

        .m-8 {
            margin: 2rem;
        }

        .my-3 {
            margin-top: .75rem;
            margin-bottom: .75rem;
        }

        .mb-8 {
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }

        .max-w-sm {
            max-width: 30rem;
        }

        .min-h-screen {
            min-height: 100vh;
        }

        .py-3 {
            padding-top: .75rem;
            padding-bottom: .75rem;
        }

        .px-6 {
            padding-left: 1.5rem;
            padding-right: 1.5rem;
        }

        .pb-full {
            padding-bottom: 100%;
        }

        .absolute {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .relative {
            position: relative;
        }

        .pin {
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .text-black {
            color: #22292f;
        }

        .text-grey-darkest {
            color: #3d4852;
        }

        .text-grey-darker {
            color: #606f7b;
        }

        .text-2xl {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }

        .text-5xl {
            font-size: 3rem;
        }

        .uppercase {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .antialiased {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        }

        .tracking-wide {
            letter-spacing: .05em;
        }

        .w-16 {
            width: 4rem;
        }

        .w-full {
            width: 100%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .md\:bg-left {
                background-position: left;
            }

            .md\:bg-right {
                background-position: right;
            }

            .md\:flex {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
            }

            .md\:my-6 {
                margin-top: 1.5rem;
                margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
            }

            .md\:min-h-screen {
                min-height: 100vh;
            }

            .md\:pb-0 {
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }

            .md\:text-3xl {
                font-size: 1.875rem;
            }

            .md\:text-15xl {
                font-size: 9rem;
            }

            .md\:w-1\/2 {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .lg\:bg-center {
                background-position: center;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased font-sans">
        <div class="md:flex min-h-screen">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 bg-white flex items-center justify-center">
                <div class="max-w-sm m-8">
                    <div class="text-black text-5xl md:text-15xl font-black">
                        429                    </div>

                    <div class="w-16 h-1 bg-purple-light my-3 md:my-6"></div>

                    <p class="text-grey-darker text-2xl md:text-3xl font-light mb-8 leading-normal">
                        Sorry, you are making too many requests to our servers.                    </p>

                    <a href="http://beta.cybasetech.com/hotcool">
                        <button class="bg-transparent text-grey-darkest font-bold uppercase tracking-wide py-3 px-6 border-2 border-grey-light hover:border-grey rounded-lg">
                            Go Home
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative pb-full md:flex md:pb-0 md:min-h-screen w-full md:w-1/2">
                <div style="background-image: url('/svg/403.svg');" class="absolute pin bg-cover bg-no-repeat md:bg-left lg:bg-center">
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like there is some HTML coming in from your call to receive the JSON. Possibly because the server is returning an error and does that in HTML format instead of an HTTP error code with JSON content.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis  yes,i am getting some html code just before exception,updated in code

Comment: you should check the response code of your HTTP request, if it is not 200 then do not attempt to parse it.  Presumably the HTML error page you see will return a non-200 response

Comment: @Jason yes.   StatusCode: 429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is returning an error because you are making too many requests.  You should check the response code of your HTTP request, if it is not 200 then do not attempt to parse it.  You may also want to try caching some of your data locally so you are not repeatedly requesting the same data from the server.